# How to show values in material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am new to react and to material-table .

I am trying to populate data in my material-table. However I am having an issue.

My code is this:

```
const columns = [
  { title: 'TDC', field: "TDC" },
  { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
  { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
];

class BasicTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ReportList: '',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MaterialTable
        title="Basic Table"
        columns={columns}
        icons={tableIcons}
        data={this.props.reportList}
        actions={[
          {
            icon: tableIcons.Delete,
            tooltip: 'Delete User',
            onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You want to delete ' + rowData.name),
          },
          {
            icon: tableIcons.Add,
            tooltip: 'Add User',
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: event => alert('You want to add a new row'),
          },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to populate data this.props.reportList which is an array of objects . The table is showing the no.of rows correctly however it is populating the columns with blank values. Does material table require a string array to populate values if so how do I do that > how do I show values in my table. on JSON.stringify- this is what is coming in the console.

```
{"ID":0,"OrgUnit":"2","TDC":"SC35","CustCode":"0000105031","CustName":"test","DestCode":"0334","EMV":"100.00","Service":"1","SPCCode":"","SPCode":"018 :018-JSR","Remarks":"No","Stage":1,"Cost":"163620.00","SAPUpdate":"","Active":"Y","CreatedBy":"TATASTEEL\\198389","CreatedOn":"2021-11-19T10:29:12.94","UpdatedBy":"TATASTEEL\\198389","UpdatedOn":"2021-11-19T10:29:12.94"},
```

{....},

how do I populate this??

Comment: You need to make sure that `this.props.reportList` should have all the keys you have defined in `columns` object with key of `field`.
Like  `surname` is not present inside your `reportList` object so the column will stay empty.

Comment: But TDC should populate right.. How do I get the value for that How do I convert that

Comment: TDC is not populating

Comment: Check this I just have created your code's copy here and it is showing data in TDC column.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-rumple-myec1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi I am getting values from a table you have just hardcoded it Am I correct in understanding that?

Comment: Correct. If you are getting values from API/Server. You need to check for values and then populate data in table. Otherwise, table won't show any value at all.

Comment: For start, just wrap your `<MaterialTable />` tag inside `if else` condition and it will start working.

Comment: I did not understand what values do I need to check for how will it work in this case??

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you mean?

Comment: @sabmit please revisit my above mentioned link. I have mocked an API by adding setTimeOut and populating data.